# Github Pages going live but not showing the html contents provided

Tags: github, github-pages, readme

I don't understand what the problem is after writing all my codes and confirming they work I pushed them and it was okay but when it went live it didn't show me the html file content it kept showing me the read me file content. please what can i do?